# How to read messages from an IRC channel using an IRC bot written in Bash?

Tags: bash, irc, bots, channel

I could not find much documentation on IRC bots written in Bash so here is my question. 
I have a simple bot that can join a channel and write messages into the channel.

However, how do I read messages from the channel, i.e. messages from users?

Ultimately, I'd like my bot to recognize a keyword that will spring the bot in action and return something. As the base of my bot, I used the script from http://www.blog.tdobson.net/node/174. Pointing me to some useful documentation on how to write IRC bots in Bash would be great as well.

Comment: While writing an IRC bot in bash is a curious novelty, it's not actually useful. Do yourself a favour and choose a real programming language suitable for this purpose.

Comment: I realize Python would be a better choice, but it's been some time since I wrote something in Python. I'm just more accustomed to Bash.

Comment: @MartinP Seriously, using bash for this makes little, to no, sense.  Your argument for using the wrong tool for the job is that you haven't used the right tool in a while..

Comment: [`ii`](http://tools.suckless.org/ii/) and [`sic`](http://tools.suckless.org/sic) might be of interest to you.

Comment: @Nick: Just because it's the wrong tool, it doesn't mean it can't do the job :) I think it would be neat to learn the networking side of Bash and an IRC bot is just where I can start. But I see I'm not getting any actual help here :-/ Thanks hinrik for those two clients!

Answer (score 2):

Leave the IRC conectivity protocol problem to be solved by [ii](http://tools.suckless.org/ii/).

It is an IRC client that generates all the output in text files (as logs) but if you write (append lines) to these files, you are actually sending commands to IRC. So it is very simple.

I recommend using `awk` for text parsing. It is a language aimed for that and easy to learn if you already do complicated bash scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The basic stream you pointed us to is this `tail -f file | telnet foo | while true; do blah; done`

This method gets the data written to file into the telnet command, but nothing takes the data from the telnet command and pipes it into the script.

Modifying the loop to support `tail -f file | telnet foo | while read f; do echo "I got message $f"; done` provides you the data being sent to you from the telnet session which you can then parse.  The problem with this strategy is that you cannot do anything spontaneously, only in response to traffic from the telnet session.

You can take care of that problem by requesting a timeout:

```
tail -f pingbot.input | telnet irc.freenode.net 6667 | while read -t 2 f || true; do
  echo I got message $f;
done
```

You will get an empty $f under timeout, a full $f if you got a message.  Parsing the PRIVMSG output from the irc protocol is left as an exercise for the reader.

The `tail | telnet | while read f; do ; done` loop is not the traditional way of accomplishing this task.  Traditionally you would set up telnet as a coprocess (coproc) instead.  But either way will probably work.